# Redux dev_mode doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, dev-mode, redux-framework

I am theme author for repository. I use Redux Framework to install theme options. But Redux embedding wasn't allowed on wordpress.org . So i have to recommend users Redux with TGM plugin at this point. As a result i must use redux builder for user to initialize my theme options.

Anyway my question is, how can i disable "Help improve our panel" warning ? So i don't want user to see that warning.

Bottom line is to fix options-init.php. But i couldn't. We should add `'dev_mode' => false` in that options-init.php. I also try add that code to setArguments function. But i am still getting warning.

I got stuck. I am awating your helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in functions.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin' ) ) {
        function redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin( $redux ) {
            if ( $redux->args['opt_name'] != 'redux_demo' ) {
                $redux->args['dev_mode'] = false;
            }
        }

        add_action( 'redux/construct', 'redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin' );
    }
```

Thank you